# FFmpeg: passing an argument for a codec

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec

I'm using FFmpeg to convert to the iLBC format:

```
ffmpeg -i dream.wav -ar 8000 -b:a 15200 -acodec ilbc dream.lbc -y
```

The [iLBC codec supports an `enhance` option](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libilbc):

> enhance
>
> Enable the enhancement of the decoded audio when set to 1. The default value is 0 (disabled).

**How am I supposed to pass that option?**

I can't seem to get it right, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i dream.wav -ar 8000 -b:a 15200 -acodec ilbc -enhance 1 dream.lbc -y
```

No matter where I place it in the command I end up with:

```
Unrecognized option 'enhance'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Is there a special syntax for arguments meant for the codec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an option for the ilbc decoder, not the encoder. For encoder specific options see `ffmpeg -h encoder=ilbc`.